# How to import js file from other js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import TodoItem.jsx to TodoList_spec.jsx.

Here's my project directory structure.

```
- TodoMVCTuts
  - app
  - bootstrap
  - config
  - database
  - node_modules
  - public
  - resources
    - assets
      - js
        - components
          - TodoItem.jsx
  - storage
  - tests
    - js
      - components
        - TodoList_spec.jsx
  - vendor
```

Here's my code:

```
// /tests/js/components/TodoList_spec.jsx
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
// ** Import TodoItem.jsx **
//import TodoItem from  '../resources/assets/js/components/TodoItem';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { List, Map } from 'immutable';
**
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not planning to use it server-side. I'm just following some tutorials about react, redux and immutable.

Comment: Anyways, how could i import it? I'm confused on how import work?

Comment: Okay. i'll remember that. Thanks. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
import TodoItem from  '../../../resources/assets/js/components/TodoItem';
```